# Import multiple xlsx files and add variable from cell, while skipping rows (R)

Tags: r, mapping, tidyverse, purrr, readxl

I have multiple Excel files where a key variable for the file is found in cell B2, but the remaining data are in rows and columns below that.

I can extract the "source" variable with the following code:

```
all_posts <- map_dfr(files, read_xlsx, range = "B2", col_names = "source")
```

However, I also need to get the additional data in the sheet that is found below B2, with code like so:

```
all_comments <- map_dfr(files, read_xlsx, skip = 5) #I need to skip five rows to where the data table starts.
```

How can I do this such that each batch of comments corresponds to the "source" variable found in cell B2? Basically, each Excel file is a "post," named in cell B2, and it contains the corresponding comments for the posts in the rows below that.

Edit: I'm adding a screenshot of one of the Excel files to better help understand my problem. [image]

Comment: Hi,
I don't really understand your situation: can you post a screenshot of a toy excel to make the problem more accessible?

Comment: Hi, I've added a screenshot to show what the files look like. I am trying to merge multiple Excel files and keep the data in cell B2 (the URL) because it corresponds to the other data in each file, namely, the comments data. I would ideally get one large dataframe with all the variables (name, profile id, date, likes, comment) AND a variable called "source" which is the post url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is using nested tibbles. I am not familiar with `read_xlsx`: I prefer `read.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` package, but I think you get the idea.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(file_name = files) %>%
  mutate(post = map_chr(file_name, ~openxlsx::read.xlsx(.x, rows = 2, cols = 2, colNames = FALSE)[1,1],
         data = map(file_name, ~openxlsx::read.xlsx(.x, startRow = 6))
```